# Custom Radio Button Not Displaying Both Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to modify some default radio buttons on a Wordpress plugin, by using just CSS only. I have inspected the webpage to get the required variables, but can't get it to work properly.

- No Thanks (Functionality works, button missing)
- Yes, Every Month (Functionality works, button displayed)

The second custom radio button displays and functions correctly...however I cannot get the first radio button to display at all (functionality from clicking the text still works, so I think it's purely a display issue).

Is there something obvious I am missing?

[image]

**Webpage Radio Button Code:**

```css
/*Remove Default Radio Button */

input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}


/*Add new radio buttons*/

[type="radio"] + span::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  vertical-align: -0.25em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  border: 0.125em solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.15em #000;
  margin-right: 0.75em;
  transition: 0.5s ease all;
}

[type="radio"]:checked + span::before {
  background: #61ce70;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25em #000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wcsatt-options-cart">
  <li>
    <label>
          <input type="radio" name="convert_to_sub" value="0">
          No thanks. 
        </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
          <input type="radio" name="convert_to_sub" value="1_month" checked="checked">
            Yes, <span class="subscription-details">every month</span>.                 
          </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed writing `<span>`

Your custom button related to `<span>` which styled `CSS`.

```css
/*Remove Default Radio Button */

input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}


/*Add new radio buttons*/

[type="radio"] + span::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  vertical-align: -0.25em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  border: 0.125em solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.15em #000;
  margin-right: 0.75em;
  transition: 0.5s ease all;
}

[type="radio"]:checked + span::before {
  background: #61ce70;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25em #000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wcsatt-options-cart">
  <li>
    <label>
          <input type="radio" name="convert_to_sub" value="0">
          <span>No thanks. </span>
        </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
          <input type="radio" name="convert_to_sub" value="1_month" checked="checked">
            <span class="subscription-details">Yes, every month</span>.                 
          </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ah I see! And where how I move the second radio button left so that its inline aswell?

Comment: Is there a way to workaround this and get the button to display if I am unable to edit the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This:

```
<ul class="wcsatt-options-cart">
  <li>
    <label>
          <input type="radio" name="convert_to_sub" value="0">
          <span class="label-wrap">No thanks.</span> 
        </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
          <input type="radio" name="convert_to_sub" value="1_month" checked="checked">
           <span class="label-wrap"> Yes, <span class="subscription-details">every month</span>.    </span>             
          </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:-

```
/*Remove Default Radio Button */
.wcsatt-options-cart input[type=radio] {
   position: absolute;
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   cursor: pointer;   
   opacity: 0;
}

.wcsatt-options-cart label { position: relative; }
/*Add new radio buttons*/

[type="radio"] + span.label-wrap::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  vertical-align: -0.25em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  border: 0.125em solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.15em #000;
  margin-right: 0.75em;
  transition: 0.5s ease all;
}

[type="radio"]:checked + span.label-wrap::before {
  background: #61ce70;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25em #000;
}
```